# Problems in integration w.r.t product measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I got a little problem. I need to verify or falsify that a function is integrable w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on ($\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}_2$). The function is as follows
$$
f(x,y)=1_{[0,\infty )\times [0,\infty )} (x,y)(e^{-x}-e^{-y})
$$
I see that $|f(x,y)|\in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}_2)$, so i use Tonelli's theorem of integration w.r.t a product measure.

$$
\int |f(x,y)| d m_2(x,y) =\int \left(  \int|f(x,y)| dm(y)\right) dm(x)
$$
I continue to calculate, and end up with the inner integral giving $+\infty$, so by intuition i would say that integrating infinity over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is again infinity, Thus the function will not be integrable.

The problem is i dont know how to handle this situation stringent and make a valid argument that its not integrable, since i dont know what to do then the integrand becomes infinite.

Any help on how to handle a situation like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x,y)|dy=\int_0^x(e^{-y}-e^{-x})dy+\int_x^{+\infty}(e^{-x}-e^{-y})dy,$$
which is not finite. If $f$ it was integrable, the last quantity would be finite for almost every $x$, which is not the case.

Comment: Okay so its holds that $f(x,y)\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}_2,m_2)$ iff the inner integral is finite?

By intuition this is obvious, but dont i need some kind of explanation that when integrating infite over a set with positive measure, its again infinite?

Comment: No, you have to replace the "iff" by a "if" (for example if the inner integral is constant equal to $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Let's  the fuction 
$
f_{\infty}(u,v)=1_{[0,+\infty)\times [0,\infty)}(u,v)\cdot\big( e^{-u}-e^{-v} \big)
$
and the sequence of fuctions 
$$
f_n(u,v)=1_{[0,+n]\times [0,+n]}(u,v)\cdot\big( e^{-u}-e^{-v} \big).
$$
Note that for all $(u,v)\in [0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$, $n\in\{0,\ldots,n,\ldots, \infty\}$
$$
|f_n(u,v)|\leq 1 
\\ 
\quad 
\\ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(u,v)|=|f_\infty(u,v)|
$$
If
$
\int |f_n(u,v)| dm_2(u,v)%\int_{0}^{n}\left(\int_{0}^{n} e^{-u}-e^{-v} dv\right)du
$
exists by [Dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int|f_n(u,v) |dm_2(u,v)=\int |f_\infty(u,v) |dm_2(u,v).
$$
But
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n(u,v)| dm_2(u,v)=\infty.
&
\end{align}